# Is there a way to control keyboard HID devices via COM port commands?

Tags: windows, input, keyboard, echo, com-port

Does anyone know if keyboard HID devices accept COM commands (via echo or other methods) to trigger keys?

Otherwise, does anyone know how to simulate key presses from a HID device itself?

I need to trigger keys from a keyboard itself from autohotkey or a stream deck, else their hotkeys are not detected in a program I'm running. This is because their hotkeys do not actually come from any HID device, therefore the rawinput interface doesn't see their hotkey triggers.